# Migrate to a new user home

Tags: permissions

I've had multiple issues with the configuration of the current user. Under a new user account these are solved. Now I want to move (not copy, because of disk space) all data from the old user to the new user. I also want to selectively move some of the unproblematic application setting files over to the new user.

To do this, How can I make the entire user folder of the old user read and writable for the new user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the ownership of the home directory using `chown` to the new user.

```
chown -R newuser:newuser /home/olduser
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that the "*multiple issues*" are actually related to application specific configuration. A vanilla account shouldn't have anything that depends on the location of the home directory.

The problem you're describing though is difficult to resolve without carrying across any issues. Copying non-"dot" files, along with the standard shell startup files might be a good start, but it's still possible you'll either miss important dot files or carry across too much. It's going to have to be a bit of a trial and error solution.

Let's assume you've already created the new account. For convenience I shall use variables to identify the old and new user directories. Perform all this as `root`:

```
olduser=olduser          # For example, « olduser=sarah »
newuser=newuser

oldgroup=oldgroup        # For example, « oldgroup=sarah » or « oldgroup=users »
newgroup=newgroup

oldhome=/home/olduser    # For example, « oldhome=/home/sarah »
newhome=/home/newuser
```

Move files from the old directory to the new:

```
mv "$oldhome"/* "$newhome/"
mv -f "$oldhome"/.{bashrc,bash_profile,profile,ssh} "$newhome/"
```

Review the remaining files, and move (`mv`) those you want to keep:

```
ls -RA "$oldhome"
```

Finally, change the ownership and group for the new user:

```
find "$newhome" -user "$olduser" -exec chown "$newuser" {} +
find "$newhome" -group "$oldgroup" -exec chgrp "$newgroup" {} +
```

Comment: Multiple issues were in KDE mostly. I've solved it with just the chown of the old user and then moving the data over and selectively application settings found in the old users home and .config. The new user works nicely. Should have done this weeks ago.